# Is it safe to return `nullptr` as a `std::shared_ptr` in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, implicit-conversion

Taking the following code snippet as a starting example:

```
template <typename FOO>
std::shared_ptr<FOO> createSharedPtr(bool yesNo) {
  if (!yesNo) {
    return nullptr;
  } else {
    return make_shared<FOO>();
  }
}
```

I have thought the `return nullptr;` statement above is compliant with C++ 11 standard, as the `nullptr` will be used to construct a `null` `std::shared_ptr` when returning to caller, as described at [cppreference shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr):

```
constexpr shared_ptr( std::nullptr_t ) noexcept;            (2)
```

However, one of my colleagues keeps insisting that he should go for `return shared_ptr<FOO>();` instead, as he cannot find any official documents nor examples that assigns `nullptr` to a `std::shared_ptr`.

Am I correct with my understanding? If yes, which document I should show him to prove my oppinion?

**UPDATED 1**

I actually did have a discussion with him, quoting the [cppreference shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), and seems that his concern is now about:

> That means that using shared_ptr() or shared_ptr(nullptr).
> But returning nullptr needs to do casting from nullptr to shared_ptr and it needs a copy constructor.

If I understand correctly, his concern is about how a `nullptr` gets constructed to become a `shared_ptr`. Regarding this, the key point is the implicit conversion from `nullptr` to `shared_ptr`. This should be equivalent to:

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int a) : a_(a) {}

 private:
  int a_;
};

A a = 1;
```

Which document should I look at to clarify the correctness of the above code?

**UPDATED 2**

Looks like [Converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) can explain the key point here. Thank you all!

Comment: Just show him the page linked from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), the constructor (1) and (2) do the same thing exactly. *1-2) Constructs a shared_ptr with no managed object, i.e. empty shared_ptr*

Answer (score 3):

They mean the same thing.  Here you can even see the generated assembly code is identical: https://godbolt.org/z/odKc4q9ja

If you prefer concision and/or dislike `nullptr`, you can `return {}` for the same effect.

Comment: I added a bit more to my question, can you please help?

Comment: Looks like you've got it all figured out now.

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague seems to confuse `std::shared_ptr<Foo>(nullptr)` with `std::shared_ptr<FOO>(static_cast<FOO*>(nullptr))`. You are correct: the mentioned overload would be already guarantee that the returned `shared_ptr` does not hold a resource.

But even `std::shared_ptr<FOO>(static_cast<FOO*>(nullptr))` is safe. From the standard, the preconditions for the ctor:

> Preconditions: The expression delete[] p, when T is an array type, or delete p, when T is not an array type, has well-defined behavior, and does not throw exceptions.

`delete static_cast<FOO*>(nullptr)` meets both conditions: it doesn't do anything.

Comment: There's a trivial difference: the `use_count` can differ depending on the constructor chosen.